# Can't get started with JNA

Tags: jna

I've just installed Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1, JDK 13, openjfx-13, and JNA-platform-5.4.0, on Win10 x64. I can't get to first base using JNA. The following code flags Native in the import statement for com.sun.jna.Native as an unknown symbol. The call to Native.load and the import statements are taken directly from https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

This screen shot shows the project library list [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaK6Q.png):

```
package jrailroad;

import com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32Util;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class ComPort
{                           // class ComPort
public int os;

public static final int OS_WINDOWS = 0;     // a Windows platform
public Kernel32 k32 = null;

ComPort()
    {                       // ComPort.ComPort
    os = -1;
    if (PlatformUtil.isWindows())
        {                   // windows
        os = OS_WINDOWS;
        k32 = (Kernel32) Native.load("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
        }                   // windows
    }                       // ComPort.ComPort
}                           // class ComPort
```

Comment: You need the core JNA package (`jna.jar`) in addition to the `jna-platform` one.

Comment: Thank you.The download page at https://github.com/java-native-access/jna  needs to say that it's necessary to download both jna.jar and jna-platform.jar, because that's not obvious.

Comment: @DanielWiddis You might want to add that as an answer so it can be accepted :)

Comment: @cubrr https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389

Answer (score 1):

As the [Getting Started](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md) link that you posted states,

> Java Native Access (JNA) has a single component, jna.jar; the
>   supporting native library (jnidispatch) is included in the jar file.
>   ... Begin by downloading the latest release of JNA and referencing
>   jna.jar in your project's CLASSPATH.

You did not include `jna.jar`, but rather you included the user-contributed mappings to various platforms, `jna-platform.jar`.  The [link you noted in your comment](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) includes links to both of these files:

> **JNA**
>
> *jna-5.4.0.jar*
>
> This is the core artifact of JNA and contains only the binding library
>   and the core helper classes.
>
> **JNA Platform**
>
> *jna-platform-5.4.0.jar*
>
> This artifact holds cross-platform mappings and mappings for a number
>   of commonly used platform functions, including a large number of Win32
>   mappings as well as a set of utility classes that simplify native
>   access.

And as mentioned in the comments, manually including `jar` files quickly becomes unsustainable when your dependencies have dependencies themselves.  You should learn how to use a package manager such as Maven, Gradle, or Ivy.  Your IDE has a process for this, just search for, e.g., "netbeans maven" for more guidance.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use a package manager for library handling. The maven artifacts for JNA contain the right dependency information and pulling in jna-platform pulls in jna as a transitive dependency. I prefer maven, but gradle and ivy should also do the right thing.

Comment: @MatthiasBläsing I echo the suggestion to use a package manager (and edited the answer) but would recommend against relying on transitive dependencies, as dependency resolution might bring in an older version of `jna.jar` if your project has another dependency (such as SpringBoot) which uses an earlier version of JNA.  See [most of these issues](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed+maven+transitive) for example.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I'd still recommend using indirect dependencies. The problems can be easily detected using e.g. the reactorModuleConvergence rule from maven-enforcer-plugin.